# Visual Studio Code: Why am I prompted to save unsaved open files when clicking on "Open Folder"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). I have a few unsaved files open. Now I wanted to open a directory via "Open Folder" and am prompted to (first) save the unsaved files. Why would that be necessary?

<sub>I don't want to save these files just yet; they are temporary scribbles.</sub>

Comment: `File > Add Folder to Workspace...` did what I had in mind... -- without prompting me to save anything...

Answer (score 0):

`File > Add Folder to Workspace...` did what I had in mind... -- without prompting me to save anything...